# Docker compose specify container network as host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, docker-run

What is the docker compose equivalent of running a docker container with network of container === host network ?

`docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx`

Basically, how to specify the `--network host` inside docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am running this by just specifying the port mappings from host to docker container, where I use the same port on both

eg :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api-server:
    build: '.'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: This is the correct approach.  You shouldn't need host networking in most cases, and it doesn't work on non-Linux host OSes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the network mode inside your service at docker-compose.yml. Add it like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  network_mode: "host"
  api-server:
    build: '.'
```